# How do I check if message content includes any items in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord

I'm making a discord bot and I'm trying to make a forbidden words list using arrays. I can't seem to find out how to make this work. Here's my current code:

```
if (forbidenWords.includes(message.content)) {
  message.delete();
  console.log(colors.red(`Removed ${message.author.username}'s Message as it had a forbidden word in it.`));
}
```

If you can't tell, I'm trying to check if the user's message has anything that's in the array `forbidenWords` and remove it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted checks if the entire message's content is a member of your array. To accomplish what you want, loop over the array and check if the message contains each item:

```
for (var i = 0; i < forbidenWords.length; i++) {
  if (message.content.includes(forbidenWords[i])) {
    // message.content contains a forbidden word;
    // delete message, log, etc.
    break;
  }
}
```

(By the way, you misspelled "forbi**dd**en" in your variable name)

Comment: Thank you for the help, i did ask a few of my friends how to do this and they got close but still, thanks for helping me

Comment: No problem. Also, you don't need to add "SOLVED" – accepting an answer automatically marks the question as such.

Comment: yeah, im not the smartest but still

Comment: im not too sure if im allowed to post my servers invite link here but i might have other questions and i dont want to keep posting on this site as i have a bad rep, if you want you can join my discord server and i might have a question and my bot will also be on it, **https://discord.gg/TMURcRx**

Comment: Nobody said anything about that. Everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

In "modern" JS:

```
forbiddenWords.some(word => message.content.includes(word))
```

In commented, line-by-line format:

```
forbiddenWords               // In the list of forbidden words,
  .some(                     // are there some
    word =>                  // words where the 
      message.content        // message content
        .includes(           // includes
          word))             // the word?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf() method instead:

```
if (forbidenWords.indexOf(message.content) != -1){
     message.delete();
     console.log(colors.red(`Removed ${message.author.username}'s Message as it had a forbidden word in it.`));
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the (broken) code the OP posted.

Comment: assuming 'message.content' is a string this code works just fine. i tested it.

Comment: What if `forbidenWords = ["foo", "bar"]` and `message.content = "foo bar"`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.S = String.fromCharCode(2);
Array.prototype.in_array = function(e){
    var r=new RegExp(this.S+e+this.S);
    return (r.test(this.S+this.join(this.S)+this.S));
};
 
var arr = [ "xml", "html", "css", "js" ];
arr.in_array("js"); 
//如果 存在返回true , 不存在返回false
```

Comment: Not only is this convoluted, but it's equivalent to `Array.includes` – which is not going to help in this situation