# Check if a message sent contains a word in an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been searching for quite awhile on how to do this. Every method I've tried has not worked.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to check if an argument in a command contains a word that is in my array.

If I run the command !add  , it should check and see if  is apart of list of teams in my array.

**What I currently have code wise:**

```
const teamNames = ['ember', 'knights' , 'spree', 'blackdragons', 'nightmare', 'thewave', 'rays', 'spartans', 'kings', 'griffins', 'barons', 'pirates'];

        if(!args[0]) {
            return message.channel.send('Add a players name!');
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++) {
                if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(teamNames[i])) {
                    message.channel.send(teamNames[i]);
                    break;
                } else {
                    message.channel.send('Please make sure the team name is correct!');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**The issue:**
When I run the command !add  ,  it doesn't fully check all of the string in the array.
For example:
When I do !add Spoon Spree, it sends the message "Please make sure the team name is correct!"

However, If I do !add Spoon Ember, it sends `teamNames[i]` (Just repeats the team name).
I'm assuming that's because it just checks the first string in the array then stops

**Resource I used to find this:** [How do I check if message content includes any items in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115137/how-do-i-check-if-message-content-includes-any-items-in-an-array)

**This isn't my full code, this is just a test command to try and figure out the issue.**

I appreciate any help given!

Comment: You want `if (teamNames.some(teamName => message.content.toLowercase().includes(teamName)))`, just like it says in [this answer (with the most votes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115499/283366)

Comment: @Phil It works! I must've overlooked that. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The question is already closed but here is a tip - check your if else statement - you do not need else part at all as weel as break instruction. Inside the loop you just check if next item is in the string. And only after you got all items cheked and nothing returned you send 'wrong team name" error.